# Does Hardened Scales interact with the undying mechanic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Would a creature with undying (like [Young Wolf](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Young%20Wolf)) get 2 +1/+1 counters instead of 1 when it dies if I had [Hardened Scales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hardened%20Scales) out?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Young Wolf would get 2 +1/+1 counters. The reminder text for Undying says

> When this creature dies, if it had no +1/+1 counters on it, **return it to the battlefield under its owner's control with a +1/+1 counter on it**.

A ruling on the Hardened Scales Gatherer page says

> “Placed on a creature you control” includes that creature entering the battlefield with +1/+1 counters on it. **If a creature would enter the battlefield with a number of +1/+1 counters on it while you control Hardened Scales, it enters with that many counters plus one**.

When Young Wolf returns to the battlefield from the graveyard, it enters the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter, so Hardened Scales makes it enter with 2 instead.